# Aligning a div underneath & horizontaly central an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Let's say I have a context menu that goes like this

```
    |here|there|somewhere|
```

which is simple

```
<ul>
    <li>here</li>
    ...
<ul>
```

with and onclick I want to add a div with an image like this:

```
    |here|there|somewhere|
            ^
```

Aligned horizontally in the middle of the element, vertically underneath it. How can I do it?

Comment: Googling. Seems like should've look at Jquery API first.

Comment: I'm assuming you also want it to disappear when you click another menu item? Or would it never disappear? Is your problem figure out how to center with the css or figure out how to add an onclick event with js?

Comment: Layouting. No problems with click() and toggle().

Comment: can you post your code that you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways, especially depending exactly on what you want to do, but here's one:

```
$("li").on('click', function () {
   $("<div>").width($(this).width())
      .css({'display': 'inline-block', 'text-align': 'center'})
      .text('here')
      .appendTo(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd add the image as a background through css to the menu item then position it in the center at the bottom:

**CSS:**

```
li { background: url(your_image_url) no-repeat center bottom; }
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('id').style.background = "url(your_image_url) no-repeat center bottom";
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#id').css('background','url(your_image_url) no-repeat center bottom');
```

Answer (score 0):

hey man use jquery offset() function for this purpose!

```
$("ul li").click( function() {
var pos = $(this).offset();
var width = $(this).width();
var height = $(this).height();
var halfW = width/2;
var widthOfImageDiv = 20; // assume that div with image has width of 20px
var halfWIMG = widthOfImageDiv/2;
var posLeft = pos.left+halfW-halfWIMG;
var posTop = pos.top+height;
$(".imageDiv").css({ 'position':'absolute', 'top':posTop+"px", 'left':posLeft+"px" });
$(".imageDiv").show();
});
```

Comment: above code is not tested! any errors in code will be accepted :)